# 8-tap daubechies wavelet decomposition in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, wavelet, decomposition

I have a code to implement 8-tap Daubechies wavelet decomposition . First I decompose in 4 levels  and the reconstruct the original image from the coefficients. code is as give below

```
Im=imread('me.jpg');
% Perform wavelet transform using Daubechies filter bank, 4th order
[LL1,HL1,LH1,HH1] = dwt2(Im,'db8');    
[LL2,HL2,LH2,HH2] = dwt2(LL1,'db8');    
[LL3,HL3,LH3,HH3] = dwt2(LL2,'db8');    
[LL4,HL4,LH4,HH4] = dwt2(LL3,'db8');  
% inverse wavelet transform
[LL3] = idwt2(LL4, HL4, LH4, HH4,'db8');
[LL2] = idwt2(LL3, HL3, LH3, HH3,'db8');
[LL1] = idwt2(LL2, HL2, LH2, HH2,'db8');
[reconstructed] = idwt2(LL1, HL1, LH1, HH1,'db8');
```

Using the above code I am getting an error message as

> ??? Array dimensions must match for binary array op.
>
> Error in ==> idwt2 at 93 x = upsconv2(a,{Lo_R,Lo_R},sx,dwtEXTM,shift)+
>   ... % Approximation.
>
> Error in ==> NoiseExtract_2 at 55 [LL2] = idwt2(LL3, HL3, LH3,
>   HH3,'db8');

At the inverse transform step the size of LL3,LL2 and LL1 are changed. How to solve this problem?

Comment: This probably happens because your image dimensions are not powers of two.  As such, try resizing your image so that each dimension is a power of two before doing the DWT decomposition.  Using [`nextpow2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nextpow2.html) in combination with [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) may help.... something like this:  `Im = imresize(Im, 2.^(nextpow2([size(Im,1) size(Im,2)])), 'bilinear');`

Comment: Exactly both rows and columns of an image should be even